Complete a multi-word phrase or REMAINDER of a line (not single word or whole line)
I know how to complete a word <c-N> or <c-P> and how to complete a whole line <c-X><c-L>. But how can I have vim complete a phrase or REMAINDER of a line?
Example:
one two three four five
three|

When my cursor is at |, I would like to be able to type a command and have vim offer to turn line 2 into three four five, i.e., to complete this line on the basis of the same phrase that appears at the end of line 1.
Alternatively, vim could offer to add the word "four", then if I repeat the command, to add "five".
Is there a way to do either of these completions?

There is no way to achieve that with Vim's built-in :help ins-completion methods, so you will have to write your own :help compl-function or find a plugin that does what you want.

I guess yypd2w won't count as an answer? No need for completion when you can just copy stuff.

With completion
You can (contrary to comments) complete repeated phrases, but it's a bit tedious: after typing thre in the new line and using Ctrl+n to complete the word, use Ctrl+x, Ctrl+n to complete the next word (and repeat for subsequent words). This is documented at :help compl-current:

    CTRL-X CTRL-N or
    CTRL-X CTRL-P   Further use of CTRL-X CTRL-N or CTRL-X CTRL-P will
            copy the words following the previous expansion in
            other contexts unless a double CTRL-X is used.

[…]

After expanding a word, you can use CTRL-X CTRL-P or CTRL-X CTRL-N to get the
word following the expansion in other contexts.  These sequences search for
the text just expanded and further expand by getting an extra word.  This is
useful if you need to repeat a sequence of complicated words.  Although CTRL-P
and CTRL-N look just for strings of at least two characters, CTRL-X CTRL-P and
CTRL-X CTRL-N can be used to expand words of just one character.
    e.g., to get:
        M&eacute;xico
    you can type:
        M^N^P^X^P^X^P
CTRL-N starts the expansion and then CTRL-P takes back the single character
"M", the next two CTRL-X CTRL-P's get the words "&eacute" and ";xico".

If the previous expansion was split, because it got longer than 'textwidth',
then just the text in the current line will be used.

If the match found is at the end of a line, then the first word in the next
line will be inserted and the message "Word from other line" displayed, if
this word is accepted the next CTRL-X CTRL-P or CTRL-X CTRL-N will search
for those lines starting with this word.

[The example is a bit garbled, to me.]
Other Methods
When I find myself doing this repeatedly for a short phrase, I tend to go yank it (?threeEntery$Ctrl+o) and paste it when I need it. This is also effective with whole lines (yy); depending on the buffer and goal, using :copy/:t can be even faster.
I also have a command :{range}ReplaceMe template_variable replacements … based on a now-deleted answer. With this command, I can create a template block and then generate multiple copies of it. For example, if the buffer contains
X three four five

then :ReplaceMe X one two generates
one three four five
two three four five

The replacement variable can occur multiple times in the template.
Here's the complete code of my ~/.vim/plugin/replaceme.vim
if exists('g:loaded_replaceme')
  finish
endif
let g:loaded_replaceme = 1

" based on https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/34561/10604
function ReplaceMe(startline, endline, toreplace, firstreplacement, ...) abort
  let template = join(getline(a:startline, a:endline), "\n")
  execute a:startline . ',' . a:endline . 'd _'
  " put! first time to so we don't move down a line the first time
  put! =substitute(template, a:toreplace, a:firstreplacement, 'g')
  for replacement in a:000
    put =substitute(template, a:toreplace, replacement, 'g')
  endfor
endfunction

command -range -nargs=+ ReplaceMe call ReplaceMe(<line1>, <line2>, <f-args>)


Thank you! The completion method is exactly what I was looking for. I've mapped it to inoremap <c-M> <c-X><c-N> so that I can hold down CTRL then type nmmmm etc.

@AlexRoberts that might cause some problems with… enter? I think C-j is the same as the enter key, but C-m is the same as what Vim calls CR (carriage return). Just a warning in case you notice something odd.

Ah, good point, I hadn't noticed that, but you're right, now the return key (on a Mac) is mapped to  as well. Is there a way to keep these separate? (i.e., to map  while leaving  untouched). Or do I just need to choose a different mapping?

In any case, I've switched it to inoremap <c-B> <c-X><c-N>, which seems to work (and I couldn't think of any feature I'd be giving up with c-B, certainly nothing as crucial as !). With that, one can hold down CTRL and then type nbbbb.

@AlexRoberts See https://bestasciitable.com/, though it may depend on terminal emulator and terminal properties nowadays (I think with modern ones you can get C-i and Tab separate?)
